# Concurrent transaction in IBExpert and Firebird 2.5.2

Tags: database, transactions, firebird, firebird2.5, ibexpert

I am trying to run following query on IBExpert

```
delete from mytable where EMPID = 55 and ROLEID = 445
```

I am getting error:

```
update conflicts with concurrent updates.
Concurrent transaction number is 292071.
```

How do I come to know which query is running behind the scenes which has acquired the lock? Is there any way in IBExpert to know that?

Comment: Instead of using IB Expert, you could also check the monitoring tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be another connection with an active and not committed update or delete on one of these records.

You can search who is responsible in IBExpert: Services | Database Monitoring.